# paths is not working in tsconfig.json as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to use `jasmine-ts` but always getting module not found error, so I decided to check that using `tsc` to figure out what is the problem, my folder structure is as follows:

```
\src\app\...
\src\tests\...
```

So I created `tsconfig.json` at '`tests`' folder level as follows

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "../", 
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": [
                "app/*"
            ] 
        }
    }
}
```

in my `*.test.ts` file, I'm importing a module inside the app dir, and yet still getting module not found error.

> Cannot find module '@app/core/data/my-module

I tried the following command

```
tsc --traceResolution test1.test.ts
```

and it gives me

```
test1.test.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@app/core/data/my-module'. 

2 import { Field } from '@app/core/data/my-module'
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: When you run `tsc --traceResolution test1.test.ts`, you aren't using the `tsconfig.json` file.  Instead run `tsc --traceResolution -p .` or just `tsc --traceResolution`, and if necessary, use the `files`, `include`, and `exclude` options in `tsconfig.json` to limit the files processed.  If that doesn't get you where you want to be, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this?:

in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@pages/*": ["app/pages/*"],
      "@environment": ["environments/environment"]
    }
  },
}
```

when importing:

```
import { LoginComponent } from '@pages/login/login.component';

import { environment } from '@environment';
```

It is working for me..

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
"baseUrl": "src"
```

instead of

```
"baseUrl": "../",
```

in your tsconfig.json

Comment: not working ... also how could it be? because src is the parent folder for tests, and the tsfoncfig is inside tests folder

Comment: Where is your core folder located. If it is inside src/app/ then what I had told in my answer is right.

Comment: yes 'core' is inside 'src/app'. I tried it and it didn't work the same error.

Comment: Did you build it again. Please restart npm.

Comment: not working, please provide plunker sample or try it yourself. it didn't work on my side.